# Is there any useful custom class(or function) for choose date?

Tags: java, datepicker, java1.4, jdatechooser, jdk1.4

I'm making program with JAVA 1.4

You should read  it again.

**JAVA 1.4**

I also want to use 1.8 but company doesn't allow it

I found **JDatePicker**

I thought it would solve my date selecting problem

however, Eclipse said *"DatePicker doesn't support version minor 1.4"*

So... I have to find another custom class/function like **JDatePicker**

Is there any useful class or function, which works at **JAVA 1.4**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but looks like this would fit your requirements: http://toedter.com/jcalendar/